# Vue JS: How to animate the blocks that move when another element is inserted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, animation, vuejs2, vue-component

Is there a way to smoothly animate the elements on the page that move when a new element is added to the DOM?

As you can see in the gif, at the moment it's abrupt:

[image: click to see the gif]

At the moment, this is how I animate the rows in the list (if it's relevant).

```html
<transition-group 
                name="list" 
                tag="div" 
                enter-active-class="animated zoomIn faster"
                leave-active-class="animated zoomOut faster">

                <LineInput v-for="(item, index) in inputRows" 
                            v-bind:key="index" 
                            v-on:textEntered="updateText"
                            v-on:rowID="deleteRow"
                            :inputID="index"
                            :inputText="item"
                            class="mt-n2" />
</transition-group>
```

Comment: You would need to animate `height` as well from `0` to `N` to make this smooth (or likely after this transition to keep the animation from looking odd.). `zoomIn` uses a `transform` which keeps the space used constant regardless of what it looks like on the screen.

Comment: Hmm, OK, I'll try that. Thanks.